# py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, py4j

I m trying to understand this code which uses Py4j. However each time I run the code I'm getting the same error. I have py4j installed in my Ubuntu 14.04. The jar file is in usr/share/py4j.

The code is

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize , sent_tokenize
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
import nltk
from nltk.tree import Tree
import os.path
import parsers

LangPaths =os.path.realpath("/home/Downloads/Abstractive Summarizer/SumMe-master/Summarizer/langdetector/profiles/")
tltagger = nltk.data.load("taggers/english.pickle")
tlChunker = nltk.data.load("chunkers/maxent_ne_chunker/english_ace_binary.pickle")
enChunker = nltk.data.load("chunkers/maxent_ne_chunker/english_ace_multiclass.pickle")
punkt_param  = PunktParameters()  #creates an opening for tokenizer parameters.
punkt_param.abbrev_types = set(['gng','mr','mrs','dr','rep']) #abbreviations further accepted goes here
sentence_splitter = PunktSentenceTokenizer(punkt_param)
tokenized = ""
gateway = JavaGateway()
detector = gateway.entry_point
detector.init(LangPaths)
```

The error which I m getting is

> File "/home/shiju/Downloads/Abstractive
>   Summarizer/SumMe-master/Summarizer/preprocessor.py", line 29, in
>   
>       detector.init(LangPaths)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 811, in __call_   answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)`
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 624, in send_command
>       connection = self._get_connection()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 579, in _get_connection
>       connection = self._create_connection()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line
>   585, in _create_connection
>       connection.start()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 697, in start
>       raise Py4JNetworkError(msg, e) py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server

I think Python is unable to connect with the Java application

Comment: This code assumes that a JVM is started and waiting for a connection.

Comment: Sorry for asking but what should i do to make sure JVM is started and working properly

Comment: Hello ! had you found out how to make JVM start and work properly like you said ?